# Salesforce- Apex error Unexpected Token

Tags: apex, compile-error

I am having a hard time writing an Apex script properly to remove all users assigned to a permission set called E2CP Case Feed End User. Here is what my error is (in Copado):

> ERROR Unexpected token 'permID'. Line: 1 Column: 4

Here is my code:

```
ID permID = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE name = 'E2CP_Case_Feed_End_User'].Id:
delete [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId = :permID];
```

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Hi Beth, welcome to SFSE! As this is the *Salesforce* Stack Exchange, no need to seek out tags with Salesforce in the name to let us know that is your subject area. The `[community]` tab is to be used for issues pertaining to the **`Salesforce Communities`** feature, which this question does not appear to be.

Comment: So sorry! It is my first post. I didn't realize all the mistakes I was making in a post according to you. I will study the post protocol before I try to ever post in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the colon `:` at the end of your first line with a semi-colon `;`.

Comment: Thank you so much!